# Both latex and parameter values in python strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, matplotlib, f-string

I want to add a title to my plots (in matplotlib) which would display both parameters and their values, something like

```
f"$\alpha$ = {present value of alpha}, $\beta$ = {present value of beta}"
```

f-strings won't display latex but will insert the present parameter values into the placeholders; r-strings will do the former but not the latter.
Any way around this?

Comment: How about an `rf`-string?